# Use SQL to delete multiple records in an excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Can we use SQL command to delete multiple records in a big excel file in excel vba.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/help and this https://stackoverflow.com/tour before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and see if you get

[image: error]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestDelete()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim sCon As String, n As Long
    sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
           ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"
    
    ' sheet1
    With Sheet1
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1) = "A"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "B"
        For n = 2 To 20
           .Cells(n, 1) = n
           .Cells(n, 2) = 0
        Next
    End With
       
    ' connect
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open sCon
    
    ' command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = con
       .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With
    
    ' select
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [A] FROM [Sheet1$]"
    MsgBox cmd.Execute(n).GetString, vbInformation, cmd.CommandText
    
    ' update
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [B]=[A]+10"
    cmd.Execute n
    MsgBox n & " records updated", vbInformation, cmd.CommandText

    ' delete
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [B] > 20"
    On Error Resume Next
    cmd.Execute n
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, cmd.CommandText
    Else
        MsgBox n & " records deleted", vbInformation, cmd.CommandText
    End If
    
End Sub
```